# Unable to resize sprite kit image sizes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, nodes, 2d-games

I am developing a sprite kit game and I am having a lot of trouble sizing by sprites. I used the following code to add the sprite to the scene

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero.png")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */


hero.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 5)

   _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.6, target: self,
selector: Selector ("spawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    self.addChild(hero)

}

func spawnBullets(){

    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")
    bullet.zPosition = -5
    bullet.position = CGPointMake(hero.position.x, hero.position.y);
    let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 0.6)
    bullet.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
    self.addChild(bullet)
```

However, every time I run my app in the simulator my hero takes up almost 80% of the screen. I tried resizing my image in photoshop (as well as resized my image in Xcode by using a different CGSize or a CGRect code) but then the image is displayed as a red X and my app crashes saying insufficient memory to process the images or something like that.

Then, I reduced the amount of pixels to 25x25 pixels thinking that it would take less processing memory but no, the images are still displayed as red x's or my app crashes.

So, either the sprites take up 80% of the screen or they don't load or alas the app crashes.

Comment: What happens if you use hero.setScale(0.5) or hero.setScale(0.25) in the case when the hero takes almost 80% of the screen. Be sure when resizing your image and added to your project target you set the right image name as before

Comment: are you using an asset catalog?

Comment: @ronatory thank you for your help! i didn't use that code exactly but it did give me an idea. This is the code i used hero.xScale = 0.5
        hero.yScale = 0.5

Comment: @GageKolman great that I could help you at least to give you an idea